# JavaFX setting window Always on top with JNA lib, windows os

Tags: java, c++, windows, javafx, jna

I have to put my application transparent window over the top of  every application//not just within application < Im aware that i can set modality on stage and put it on top bud thats not what i look for >// (same functionality as swing's setAlwaysOnTop(true)),bud since this is JavaFX application i dont have this option yet.So i decided to go native, i have JNA class

```
public interface Kernel32 extends StdCallLibrary {

    public static class WinOnTop extends Structure {

        public HWND  hWnd;
        public HWND  hWndInsertAfter;
        public int X;
        public int Y;
        public int cx;
        public int cy;
        public int uFlags;

        @Override
        protected List getFieldOrder() {
            return Arrays.asList(new String[]{"hWnd", "hWndInsertAfter", "X", "Y", "cx", "cy", "uFlags"});
        }

    }

    boolean SetWindowPos(HWND hWnd, HWND hWndInsertAfter, int X, int Y, int cx,
            int cy, int uFlags);

}
```

And resource i use to create it is

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

In my main i create object as:

```
 public static Kernel32 kernel;

    static{
        kernel=(Kernel32)Native.loadLibrary("Kernel32", Kernel32.class);
    }
```

This is my first time that i try to add some native functionality into my application.

**My question is how do i preceed? How can i say that THIS IS THE STAGE THAT I WANT TO APPLY THIS FUNCTIONALITY TO , i really need to point to the right direction as i dont know what im doing atm with JNA**

I have seen some tutotial on how to acess time bud its only working with simple variable,How can i connect thos function with my Transparent Stage?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Don't use JNA, use [Java8u20](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html#setAlwaysOnTop-boolean-) or any other subsequent version, which has a JavaFX always on top feature.

```
stage.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
```

There is a [nice blog post by Carl Dea on always on top](http://carlfx.wordpress.com/2014/05/19/javafx-8u20-days-of-future-past-always-on-top/).

Comment: wasnt aware of 8u20,this will make it simple.Thanks

Comment: I don't see it, and its not listed in the feature changes.   Maybe with the next one.

Comment: @Stephen [stage.setAlwaysOnTop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html#setAlwaysOnTop-boolean-) is in the current Java version (8u20), you don't need to wait for the next one.

Comment: @Stephen Wille If you dont see it maybe your project still use 8 not 8u20, try to change version of JDK that your project uses.